What is this graph?
I am seeking nomenclature to describe the family of graphs detailed below, and literature about its processing, traversal, costs, etc. Any and all input is welcome, e.g. papers, textbooks, helpful jargon, advice to avoid or modify the structure, etc.
Graph construction
We start with a N-ary, perfectly height-balanced, weighted, bidirectional tree. I am using these labels to mean:

N-ary: each node has at most N children, known in advance, where N is a power of 2 (e.g. 2, 4, 8, 16, ...). Additionally, every node has strictly a power of 2 number of children (e.g. there are no nodes with 3 children).
perfectly height-balanced  [1]: all leaf nodes are the same distance (i.e. number of edges) from the root node.
weighted: edges are weighted, although not by a numerical scalar; instead by symbolic expressions from a finite collection much smaller than the number of edges. In an implementation, edges would maintain merely an index to a symbolic expression among the collection.
bidirectional: edges point in both directions, so nodes have pointers to their children and their parents. This is because we sometimes need to DFS up from a leaf to the root, but on other occassions we BFS down from the root or another node. Note these directions do not have distinct weights. While this just seems like the typical undirected edges of a tree, we importantly maintain this property when generalising our tree to a graph as we will below.

A tree as described so far might resemble (where colour unimportantly signifies parent node outdegree, and edges are drawn pointing down but can be traversed in both directions):

Now we make the following changes:

we permit nodes to have multiple parents, by permitting new edges between adjacent layers in the above described trees. A node however can only have a power-of-2 number of parents, also bounded by N (the maximum number of children).
we permit multiple source nodes so there is no unique root node.

Such a graph (hiding weights) could resemble:

This is the graph type I seek to name and better understand. It generalises our tree to a graph where root(s) become "source nodes" (indegree of zero) and leaves become "sink nodes" (outdegree of zero), with the following properties:

levelled: all sink nodes are the same distance (number of edges) from every source node.
layered: all of a node's parents are in the same layer, i.e. are the same distance from every source node (as implied by above anyway).
acyclic: while our edges are bi-directional, we will only ever traverse "always up" or "always down"; with respect to a direction, our graph is a DAG.

It's not necessarily true that our new graph is connected; source nodes can have their own subgraphs, but that's not important to me.
Graph pruning
Finally, I am also interested in pruning these graphs by removing a node, all of its descendents, and all of its ancestors which have no other children. In this manner:

the graph (when imagined a multi-root tree) stays perfectly balanced (we do not elevate any nodes to sink nodes) with respect to their minimum distance to a source node; some nodes are disconnected from a source node when traversing "only up" for example.
we relax the number of children from being a power of 2; now a node can have e.g. 3 children, because its fourth was deleted.
we maintain the number of parents being a power of 2, because no nodes ever lose a parent; they would be deleted along with it.

For example, we might prune the previous graph into the red subgraph below:

Does this pruned family of graphs have a name, or other properties I have missed?
Application
In our application, we dynamically create such a graph, layer by layer, pruning as we go to keep the whole graph size tractable. Then, we repeatedly re-traverse the graph, substituting parameters into the symbolic edge weights and numerically evaluating them, and aggregating them via dynamic programming. We might perform this heirarchal reduction thousands of times. We never need to search the tree; we will always traverse completely through it from one direction (from source nodes or sink nodes).
All of this is to simulate quantum channel through the "Pauli propogation" method, as demonstrated here. The entire graph can be interpreted to encode a single, giant, symbolic expression (corresponding to an analytic approximation of an operator's expected value under states produced by the channel) which we numerically evaluate heirarchally through traversal. If our graph were a tree, I think we could classify it as an "expression tree".
What I want to know
Anything and everything about this family of graphs!

Is it named, or mentioned in literature?
Do you think it is more illustrative to call it a "merged, pruned, perfectly-balanced, 2^N-ary tree generalisation", or a "directed, acyclic, levelled, layered, 2^N-ary, power-of-2-outdegree-ary graph"?
Do you have suggestions for its efficient implementation, or reservations about its design?
Are there existing algorithms for its efficient, parallelised creation or traversal?
The entire graph can be interpreted to encode a single, giant, symbolic expression which we numerically evaluate heirarchally through traversal. Does this context classify the graph into a special family, like an "expression tree"?

All input is sincerely appreciated!

Just a guess, but I would be shocked to see any preesxisting literature on such a graph, let alone a name.

@EnEm I'm not so pessimistic; it seems a natural graph to describe the evaluation of an expression with a finite alphabet. I.e. take the leaves as the current ensemble of words to be operated upon, each producing one or more words, and merge the duplicates in the new leaf layer
